# TailwindCSS headlessui Switch doesn't work with IntertiaJS useForm() field

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, tailwind-css, inertiajs, headless-ui

I'm attempting to use the Tailwind headlessui [`<Switch>` component](https://headlessui.com/vue/switch) in a Vue3/InertiaJS app, and when I put it in my component as it is in the docs, using an enabled `ref()` variable for the value, it works fine.  However, when I bind it via `v-model` to a `useForm()` value like so:

```
<script setup>
const form = useForm({
   enabled: false
    ...
})
</script>

<template>
<Switch
    v-model="form.enabled"
    ...
>
</template>
```

it doesn't work. Instead, the button doesn't work at all, and there are no console errors. I have many other fields in the same form that work fine with the form fields, so its' just this one. The only difference I can see is that the examples use `ref()`, and `useForm()` uses `reactive()`, but I can't see why that would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, there is no error in your description of the problem. I’ll give an approximate usage algorithm, maybe it will help

1. Install inertiajs for vue

   ```
   npm install @inertiajs/inertia-vue3
   yarn add @inertiajs/inertia-vue3
   ```
2. Import `useForm` from inertiajs in your component

   ```
   import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
   ```
3. Create a form object:

   ```
   const form = useForm({
     enabled: null,
     ...
   })
   ```
4. We use it in the component template as:

   ```
   import { Switch } from "@headlessui/vue";
   ...
   <Switch
      v-model="form.enabled"
   ```

Full code:

```
<template>
  <div class="p-6">
    <Switch
      v-model="form.enabled"
      @update:modelValue="test"
      :class="form.enabled ? 'bg-blue-600' : 'bg-gray-200'"
      class="relative inline-flex h-6 w-11 items-center rounded-full"
    >
      <span class="sr-only">Enable notifications</span>
      <span
        :class="form.enabled ? 'translate-x-6' : 'translate-x-1'"
        class="inline-block h-4 w-4 transform rounded-full bg-white transition"
      />
    </Switch>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { useForm } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";

import { Switch } from "@headlessui/vue";

const form = useForm({
  enabled: false,
});
</script>
```

and an [example in action](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/inertia-vue3-headlessui-vue3-khfksz?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue%3A1%2C1-31%2C10)

Answer (score 0):

Credit to the answer above by @mikalai-parakhnevich, I was missing the form reference for the `:class` binding. I did not need the `@update:modelValue` line.

```
<SwitchGroup>
    <Switch
        v-model="form.enabled"
        :class="form.enabled ? 'bg-gray-200' : 'bg-white'"
        class="relative inline-flex h-6 w-11 items-center rounded-full"
    >
    <span class="sr-only">Me label</span>
    <span
        :class="form.enabled ? 'translate-x-6' : 'translate-x-1'"
        class="inline-block h-4 w-4 transform rounded-full bg-indigo-600 transition"
    />
    </Switch>
    <SwitchLabel class="mx-4">My label</SwitchLabel>                   </SwitchGroup>
```